# How to make script type both text/babel and module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

It works perfectly because I haven't included JSX, but when I replace the script type with `text/babel`, it doesn't work because the module fails to load. `browser.js` the Babel compiler.

Here... JSX works only when i replace script type with `text/babel` but the problem is module fails to load since the script is not module. Any idea how make it work with JSX?

```
<div id="root">

</div>
<script type="module">
    import  './react.min.js';
    import  './react-dom.min.js';
    import  './browser.js';
    class Hello extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: [Follow this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883713/using-es-modules-with-babel-standalone/64472452#64472452) it should answer your question

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE July 2021**

As per [mh sattarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5863267/mh-sattarian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956469/2503826) you now don't need `data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"` to use native es6 module's import/export etc. Instead you simply add `data-type="module"`

**Original Answer**

Just in case if some one comes here looking for answer

There is a support for data-plugins and data-presets in babel standalone

```
<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" type="text/babel">
```

see more here
[Babel standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone/)

Comment: What worked for me is the following `<script src="../src/App.js" type="text/babel"  data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" defer ></script>
      <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" defer></script>`

Comment: May be because you are using something thats not part of es2015 like optional chaining or something that is part of es2020 @tarekahf

Comment: This is confusing like hell, just saying!

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone), it's added in: `v7.10.0`.

> If you want to use your browser's native support for ES Modules, you'd
> normally need to set a `type="module"` attribute on your script tag.
>
> With @babel/standalone, set a `data-type="module"` attribute instead,
> like this:
>
> `<script type="text/babel" data-type="module">`

Answer (score 4):

I think the question was if it is possible to use a script tag with two or more types at the same time (e.g. something like `type="module, txt/babel"`). As far as I know the answer is NO.

JonDotsoy's answer helps with reduce typing `React.createElement` over and over again but even with such a "variable shortcut" it's not as comfortable as JSX when using larger templates with nested elements because `h('div', {}, 'hello!!')...` is difficult to maintain in such cases.

The only way I found to combine native browser module support and in-browser Babel for JSX without using any build tool is this ... a rather dirty hack that uses `eval` and should not be used for production apps:

index.html

```
<body>

    <div id="app"></div>


    <!-- Scripts ------- -->
    <script src="vendor/js/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js" type="module"></script>

</body>
```

app/app.js

```
import ComponentOne from "./ComponentOne.js";


let template = `
<div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <hr />
    <ComponentOne msg="MsgText-ComponentOne" />
</div>
`;


const App = () => {
    return (
        eval(Babel.transform(template, { presets: ['es2017', 'react'] }).code)
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(App, null),
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

app/ComponentOne.js

```
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo.js";


let template = `
<div>
    <h2>This is ComponentOne</h2>
    <p key="2">Property "msg" content: {props.msg}</p>

    <ComponentTwo msg="MsgText-ComponentTwo" />
</div>
`;


const ComponentOne = (props) => {
    return(
        eval(Babel.transform(template, { presets: ['es2017', 'react'] }).code)
    );
};

export default ComponentOne;
```

app/ComponentTwo.js

```
let template = `
<div>
    <h2>This is ComponentTwo</h2>
    <p key="2">Property "msg" content: {props.msg}</p>
</div>
`;


const ComponentTwo = (props) => {
    return(
        eval(Babel.transform(template, { presets: ['es2017', 'react'] }).code)
    );
};

export default ComponentTwo;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may prefer to use an alias to `createElement`. This way is faster for the engine.
For example use `h` or `e`.

```
const { createElement: h } = React;

const App = () => {
   return h('div', {}, 'hello!!'); 
}
```

Otherwise, it is possible to use `@babel/standalone` module, please see more on here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html.

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- Load Babel -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your custom script here -->
<script type="text/babel">
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
    return <div>hello!!</div>
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```