# Django: how to make React and export/import work in a single JS static file?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, babeljs

In my Django template, I am loading React via CDN and also loading the `index.js` script from static url where the React code lives:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        {% load static %}
        <head>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>  
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
        <script src="{% static 'react/js/index.js' %}" type="text/babel"></script>
    </html>
```

Index.js is:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return <div>App</div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This works fine. But I also have `helpers.js` script sitting in the same `static` directory as `index.js` and if I try to import something from it in `index.js`:

```
import { some_helper } from './helpers.js'

class App extends React.Component { ...
```

I get

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

error in the browser console.

I could change the script type to `module` to make import/export work, but then React would not work. So instead I included `require` over CDN in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        {% load static %}
        <head>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>  
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
        </head>
```

but then I get the following error in the console:

> Error: Module name "helpers.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _.
>   Use require([]) https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

and I don't know how to move on from there.

Could someone guide me how to have make both React and import/export work in a single JS file?

If this is not an issue, I'd rather stick with loading React over CDN.

Comment: Check if this answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018182/how-to-make-script-type-both-text-babel-and-module