# Can I give two types to a single JS script file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react CDN in my website to make some part of the page reactive. I don't know how I can combine both type into one like **type="module,text/babel"**

```
<script type="text/babel" src="script_file" />
```

and

```
<script type="module" src="script_file />
```

**Babel** for JSX and **module** so I can use Import/export in the files to include one file function into another file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make script type both text/babel and module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018182/how-to-make-script-type-both-text-babel-and-module)